# Better debug console output for errors in react StatelessComponent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stateless

The new react 0.14 StatelessComponent is nice. However, when there is an error in its render method, react only prints this to the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child 
(found: Mon Nov 23 2015 06:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time)). If 
you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the 
object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render 
method of `StatelessComponent`.
```

Is there a way to annotate the component with a `displayName`?

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution already by trying: add the `displayName` to the components function like that:

```
const component = (props) => {
  return (<div />)
}
component.displayName = "MyComponent"
module.exports = component
```

Then, react smart as it is, will use this `displayName`. Kind of what you would expect from the great react lib ;)